# Is there a way of loading an SVG drawing asynchronously with SkiaSharp?

Tags: svg, skiasharp

I am using SkiaSharp to load an SVG drawing. It's a site plan, so is reasonably complex, and it takes a long time to load. On my Samsung Galaxy phone, it's about 3 seconds, and during that time the phone completely locks up, which is quite unacceptable.

I am using `SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg`, but cannot find an asynchronous version of the `Load()` method. Is there one? Or maybe a better way of doing this?

I am overlaying obejcts on top of the site plan and it has taken me some considerable time to get all the scaling and alignment sorted, so if at all possible, I'd like to stick with SkiaSharp rather than start with something completely different from scratch.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

3 seconds does sound a bit long...

It may not be the SVG part, but rather the loading of the file off the file system.

Either way, you might be able to just load the whole think in a background task (pseudocode):

```
var picture = Task.Run(() => {
    var stream = LoadStream();
    var svg = LoadSvg(stream);
    return svg.GetPicture();
});
```